# ReactNative (Metro)

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

When try to start Metro in Mac mini 10.15.7 given this error.
RN project created succesfully.

Using cmd => npm start --reset-cache

error No Metro config found

Start Metro and try to run project in Android side using VS code.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try below command

```
npm i metro-config --save-dev
```